# Perl: why are these not equivalent?

Tags: regex, perl

```
m/(?<=\n)(?=$pattern)/
```

vs

```
m/(?<=\n)(?=^$pattern)/
```

The semantic is I want to match the "empty string" between a new line character and a pattern.

However, in Perl, the top one does what I want while the 2nd one doesn't.

Could someone explain the intricacies at play here with the "^" meta character?

Thanks

Comment: You are probably better off with `/(?=^$pattern)/m` as the `(?<=\n)` is unnecessary with `^` in place. Also your own patterns don't match at the start of the first line

Comment: Please resolve [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28619232) before asking more. We cannot help you with that unless you show some context in your code.

Answer (score 7):

`^` defaults to matching the beginning of the string; if you want to match the beginning of a line, you need to use the `/m` flag or `(?m:^)`.